# Cache zip files (and other files) with AJAX / XHR?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, xmlhttprequest, zip

I am using some Javascript to load a zip file. I cannot seem to cache the zip file, no matter what I do. There's always a "no-cache" added to Pragma and Cache-Control in the request header. I don't add these -- the browser (at least Chrome, FF) does.

Using eg.: http_request.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "Public") right before http_request.send does add that, but it's immediately overridden: the header shows up as "Public, no-cache".

Is there any way to override this behavior? No jquery please! I need to know how to do it with XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi! The simplest solution was right in front of me the whole time. A GET response will allow me to cache my AJAX request!